# How can I achieve the card like effect in screenfeeder app

Tags: objective-c, ios, components

Can anyone guide me how can I achieve the card like effect in [screenfeeder app](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2miCBkA57Ho)?
To more specific, I have use the core data to store the book entity. I know how to use the tableviewcontroller to display the books list from core data. But I wish to use the card like effect in screenfeeder to display the books list and I have no clue how to get started.